# Using apex domain registered at WordPress

Tags: wordpress, dns, github

I have a domain registered at WordPress, let's say it's `example.com`.

I have my webpage hosted with GitHub pages and was able to add a CNAME record in the WordPress DNS settings pointing to said `github.io` page. However, this CNAME record is only for the subdomain `wwww.example.com`, as I can't simply take the apex domain `example.com`.

Now I can access my website with `www.example.com`, but `example.com` leads to the WordPress WIP page.

Is there any way to make the apex domain also lead to my `github.io` page?

I read https://docs.github.com/en/pages/configuring-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site/managing-a-custom-domain-for-your-github-pages-site and tried to add AAAA records, but if I don't give any subdomain, WordPress always puts @ there.

Comment: When you say "at WordPress" do you mean that you are using `wordpress.com` as your domain registrar?

Comment: yes, that's what I meant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> WordPress always puts @ there

That is exactly what you want. In DNS records `@` represents the domain apex (ie. no subdomain).

You will want to follow GitHub's instructions for creating `A` and `AAAA` records to get your domain apex to work. The `A` records are more important than the `AAAA` records.  `AAAA` records are for IPv6 which most people are not using yet.  `A` records are for IPv4 which will be used by the vast majority of users reaching your site.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! I only added the AAAA records, since I thought it was an either/or thing. Now it works.